# ORACLE SQL deleting the results of a query with a join

Tags: oracle, inner-join, sql-delete

I have this select that uses a inner join operating properly and get the expected resultsand exported these results as insert statements. I have followed several examples found here but can't seem to get the statement formed properly.

```
select a.*  from app_access A inner join  PERSL B on A.empid = B.EMPID and B.CAD_CMD_MASK=7864320;
```

I would like to delete the results of this query. This is where I am right now. I cannot seem to get the statement properly formed after following several examples found here.

```
delete a.* from app_access where app_access A inner join  PERSL B on A.empid = B.EMPID and B.CAD_CMD_MASK=7864320;
```

A little background - this is in a DEV database and I have written the results of the select as insert statements. I would like to remove these records in PRODUCTION and use the insert to put in the updated records from DEV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
delete app_access 
where empid IN (SELECT B.EMPID FROM PERSL B WHERE B.CAD_CMD_MASK=7864320)
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` might be one option.

As I don't have you tables, have a look at example based on Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables.

Current data in department 10:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where d.deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
```

Reuse that query for deleting these rows:

```
SQL> delete from emp a
  2  where exists (select null
  3                from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4                where d.deptno = 10
  5                  and e.empno = a.empno
  6               );

3 rows deleted.
```

Is anything left?

```
SQL> select count(*) From emp where deptno = 10;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

No, everything has been deleted.

Comment: The count count combined with the answer below made a perfect combination.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL using EXISTS should do it:

```
delete from app_access a
where exists
   (select 'x' from persl b 
    where b.empid = a.empid 
    and b.cad_cmd_mask = 7864320);
```

However, I noticed you wrote:

"I would like to remove these records in PRODUCTION and use the insert to put in the updated records from DEV."

Do you mean you're going to delete the records in Production, then update them in DEV, and then insert the updated records back into Production?  If so, why not just update them in production instead of deleting?  You could still insert the records into DEV first, and test out the update there before doing so in Production.

Comment: Phil - Vice-versa. I copied the PERSL table from  production to DEV and made edited and inserted new records in DEV. I can copy the PERSL table back to PROD, I used the application U/I to enter and edit records. This method writes to a couple of other tables.

Hopefully I can use this method to insert the records into the related tables in PROD without having to go through ha clunky U/I. I think your last sentence defines what I am attempting